# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processorMetrics' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator, open-telemetry

When I run my application in kubernetes cluster, I get the below exception and it does not come up.

```
2024-02-21 10:52:17,206 ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication [main] Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processorMetrics' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/SystemMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.system.ProcessorMetrics]: Factory method 'processorMetrics' threw exception with message: null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:654) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:488) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1640) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.resolveStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2142) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.orderedStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2136) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryPostProcessor.applyBinders(MeterRegistryPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MeterRegistryPostProcessor.java:92) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:984) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
at com.mavenir.cms.Application.main(Application.java:80) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[cms-service-0.0.1.war:0.0.1]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[cms-service-0.0.1.war:0.0.1]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[cms-service-0.0.1.war:0.0.1]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) ~[cms-service-0.0.1.war:0.0.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.system.ProcessorMetrics]: Factory method 'processorMetrics' threw exception with message: null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:263) ~[?:?]
at java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147) ~[?:?]
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.CgroupUtil.lambda$readStringValue$1(CgroupUtil.java:67) ~[?:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.CgroupUtil.readStringValue(CgroupUtil.java:69) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemController.getStringValue(CgroupSubsystemController.java:65) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemController.getLongValue(CgroupSubsystemController.java:124) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.getLongValue(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:190) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.getHierarchical(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:160) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.initSubSystem(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:85) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.getInstance(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:61) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemFactory.create(CgroupSubsystemFactory.java:120) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemFactory.create(CgroupSubsystemFactory.java:90) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.CgroupMetrics.getInstance(CgroupMetrics.java:183) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.SystemMetrics.instance(SystemMetrics.java:29) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.Metrics.systemMetrics(Metrics.java:58) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.platform.Container.metrics(Container.java:43) ~[?:?]
at com.sun.management.internal.OperatingSystemImpl.<init>(OperatingSystemImpl.java:183) ~[?:?]
at com.sun.management.internal.PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.getOperatingSystemMXBean(PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.java:280) ~[?:?]
at com.sun.management.internal.PlatformMBeanProviderImpl$3.nameToMBeanMap(PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.java:199) ~[?:?]
at sun.management.spi.PlatformMBeanProvider$PlatformComponent.getMBeans(PlatformMBeanProvider.java:195) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(ManagementFactory.java:687) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean(ManagementFactory.java:389) ~[?:?]
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.system.ProcessorMetrics.<init>(ProcessorMetrics.java:81) ~[micrometer-core-1.11.4.jar!/:1.11.4]
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.system.ProcessorMetrics.<init>(ProcessorMetrics.java:76) ~[micrometer-core-1.11.4.jar!/:1.11.4]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.SystemMetricsAutoConfiguration.processorMetrics(SystemMetricsAutoConfiguration.java:59) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
... 37 more
```

Im using springboot 3.1.4 and JDK 17.0.8

When I run the application in my local, its working fine.
I see that it is related to otel service. I don't have any services deployed related to OTEL.
But I have a grafana service.

please help.